# Using ReplyingKafkaTemplate across two different applications

Tags: spring-kafka

I have a spring boot application1 that send a message to `request` topic. On receiving this message a different spring boot application2 consumes message does processing and sending response in `response` topic. Can I use [replying-template](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#replying-template) in application1 for this integration. In application2 do I need make changes so that correlational is sent back while sending response in application2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If application2 uses a `@KafkaListener` with a non-void return type, the listener adapter will take care of the correlation id.

If it's a `void` `@KafkaListener` and you are sending the reply with a `KafkaTemplate` (or some other means) then, yes, you need to propagate the correlation id header from the inbound message into the reply.

Comment: It used void @KafkaListener and will propagate correlation id. Thank you!